# Como pegar o valor de um inputtext e gerar uma URL de IMG

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Como eu posso pegar o valor X de um INPUT e gerar uma URL para IMG usando JavaScript?

**Exemplo:**

- Coloquei o numero 505050 no form e dei submit;

**Código do Form:**

```
<form action="teste" method="GET"> 
<input name="qtdfor" type="text" class="inputtext" size="10" maxlength="10"> 
<input type="Submit" name="botaoEnviar" value="Enviar"> 
</form>
```

Como que eu faço para o Valor 505050 seja concatenado com .jpg ja dentro da tag IMG assim?

**TAG da IMG:**

```
<img src="https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/**505050**.jpg" alt="Foto perfil" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: A unica coisa que vai mudar é a id da imagem?

Comment: Isso:   <img src="https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/XXXXXX*.jpg" alt="Foto perfil" height="42" width="42">

Comment: Sempre vai pegar o valor do input e adicionar ali no XXXX

Comment: E também: se precisar que seja em JavaScript puro, por favor adicione essa informação também... já vão 2 respostas com jQuery

Comment: Algumas das respostas lhe serviu @ErickAmoedo?

Comment: Olá @Danilo! Deu certo sim, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom eu acho que é isso que você pediu. Estou usando o jQuery para facilitar um pouco. Segue o código:

```js
$("#btnInput").on("click",function(e){
 var urlFixa = "https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/";
    var valorInput = $("#campoInput").val();
    var urlFinal = urlFixa + valorInput + ".jpg";
    $("#campoInput").attr("src",urlFinal);
    $("#srcImg").html(urlFinal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="campoInput" />
<button id="btnInput" name="button">Carrega url img</button><br><br>
<img alt="Foto perfil" height="42" width="42" />
<div id="srcImg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

tem uma solução assim, com jquery:

```js
$('#botao').click(function () {
    var num = $('#num').val();
    $('#img').attr('src', "https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/" + num + ".jpg");
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<input name="qtdfor" id="num" type="text" class="inputtext" size="10" maxlength="10">
<button id="botao" name="botaoEnviar">Enviar</button>
<img src="https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/**505050**.jpg" id="img" alt="Foto perfil" height="42" width="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, dê um ID para a imagem (ex: foto):

```
<img src="https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/**505050**.jpg" alt="Foto perfil" height="42" width="42" id="foto" />
```

Crie um arquivo javascript com o codigo abaixo e importe na segunda pagina onde tem a imagem.

```
(function(){
 var akira = location.search.match('.*qtdfor=([^=&]*)');
 var foto = document.getElementById('foto');
 foto.setAttribute('src', "https://localhost/sig/_downloadFoto?parametro2=Alunos/"+akira[1]+".jpg");
})()
```

Na primeira pagina irá submeter os dados (qtdfor) via GET, e na segunda pagina (/teste) recuperará o dado submetido.

Comment: Importante importar após a tag `<img>`;